# 3D div transformation resetting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transformation

I successfully created a div that the user can "rotate". It works perfectly, except that rotating on the X direction cancels/resets the existing rotation in Y direction and vise versa. Also the div is a draggable object from jQuery. How can I fix this so that transformations are not reset?

```
<script>
var degreesY = 0; 
function rotateLeft() {
    var degreesuseY = degreesY + 10; 
    document.getElementById("Notes").style["transform"]= "rotateY(" + degreesuseY + "deg)";
}

var degreesX = 0; 
function rotateUp() {
    var degreesuseX = degreesX + 10; 
    document.getElementById("Notes").style["transform"]= "rotateX(" + degreesuseX + "deg)";
}
</script>

<div id="draggable">
    <div class="LeftRotate" onclick="rotateLeft();degreesY=degreesY+10"></div>
    <div class="UpRotate" onclick="rotateUp();degreesX=degreesX+10"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you set the `transform` property, you're rewriting the current value and erasing what you have so far.  Try changing your code to work instead with a single `rotate()` function and set the `transform` property as follows:

```
var degreesX = 0;
var degreesY = 0;
function rotate(xAxis) { //Make xAxis a boolean
    if (xAxis) {
        degreesX+=10;
    } else {
        degreesY+=10;
    }
    document.getElementById("Notes").style["transform"] = "rotate(" + degreesX + "deg " + degreesY + "deg)";
}
```

I put a simple example (using jQuery) in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/posgarou/9pnj2/).

You could avoid using xAxis, if you want, by having the function determine whether the element clicked has class `UpRotate` or `LeftRotate`.

Comment: This technically works. I just needed to change a few lines of code: document.getElementById("Notes").style["transform"] = 'rotateX(' + degreesX + 'deg)' + 'rotateY(' + degreesY + 'deg)';

Comment: Oh, I had a typo in my answer. If you delete the comma between the x and y values in the transform statement, it should work. But rotatex/y works, too.